# AJAX request errors out with no response

Tags: node.js, ajax, webix

I have an application with webix on UI and node js on server side.

From the UI if I trigger a long running AJAX request for e.g. process 1000 records, the request errors out after 1.5 mins (not consistently) approximately.

The error object contains no information about the reason for request failure but since processing smaller set of records seems to work fine I am thinking of blaming it on timeout.

From the developer console I see that request seems to be Stalled and response is empty.

Currently I cant drop a request and keep polling it after every few seconds to see if the processing has been finished. I have to wait for the request to finish but I am not sure how to do it as webix forum doesn't seem to have any information on this except for setting timeout.

If setting timeout is the way to go then what would happen tomorrow if the request size goes to 2000 records - I don't want to keep on increasing the timeout

Also, if I am left with no choice how would I implement the polling. If I drop a request on to server there can be other clients as well who are triggering a similar request. How would I distinguish between requests originated from different clients?

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: In principle, every HTTP request is meant to be one action. Request...Wait...Response. You could simply increase the request timeout significantly and let the client wait, there's nothing wrong with that except that it doesn't work well when the connection drops for some reason (think mobile clients). This would be easiest.

Comment: Another idea would be to return the first response immediately with a unique "job ID" that's hard to guess and independent of the request parameters (like a GUID). The client can then use that GUID to make subsequent requests if their data is ready. However, *anyone* who knows the GUID would be able to request that data, so it's at least necessary to use HTTPS to transfer it securely. This would still be relatively easy because no authentication scheme is needed.

Comment: You can juice up that job-based approach as much as you like. Add separate user accounts, authentication, sessions, long polling, a pub-sub model, web workers on the client... However, you need to think about some sort of flood protection, because it would be way too easy to DOS the server with work requests.

Comment: @Tomalak I like the idea of GUID but isnt that almost like polling for readiness?

Comment: That's precisely what it is. There is nothing wrong with polling. You could implement websockets if you don't like the idea of polling, but for a server that basically does batch jobs and is ready at some point in the future without having much to say in the meantime, letting the client ask "Is it ready yet?" every 10 seconds is a completely fine approach. Not super fancy but robust and low-maintenance.

Comment: @Tomalak Sounds good. I guess thats the way I'll go

Comment: You can always make it more fashionable once it works and you see the need.